# Unable to deploy twitter-bootstrap-rails gem on Heroku because therubyracer fails compilation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, ruby-on-rails-3.2, twitter-bootstrap-rails, therubyracer

I have the following gem in my Gemfile:

```
gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails', :github => 'seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails'
```

Which is for this project: https://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails

One of the dependencies is therubyracer ( https://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails/blob/master/twitter-bootstrap-rails.gemspec#L27 ):

```
s.add_dependency          'therubyracer', '>= 0.11.0beta5'
```

However, when I try and push this to Heroku I get the following error:

```
Installing therubyracer (0.11.0beta8) with native extensions
       Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
       /usr/local/bin/ruby extconf.rb
       checking for main() in -lpthread... yes
       creating Makefile
       make
       g++ -I. -I/tmp/build_1feat0v36ur6g/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/libv8-3.11.8.3-x86_64-linux/vendor/v8/include -I/usr/local/include/ruby-1.9.1/x86_64-linux -I/usr/local/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/backward -I/usr/local/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I.   -Wall -g -rdynamic -fPIC -O3 -ggdb -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-long-long   -o template.o -c template.cc
       g++ -I. -I/tmp/build_1feat0v36ur6g/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/libv8-3.11.8.3-x86_64-linux/vendor/v8/include -I/usr/local/include/ruby-1.9.1/x86_64-linux -I/usr/local/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/backward -I/usr/local/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I.   -Wall -g -rdynamic -fPIC -O3 -ggdb -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-long-long   -o array.o -c array.cc
       g++ -I. -I/tmp/build_1feat0v36ur6g/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/libv8-3.11.8.3-x86_64-linux/vendor/v8/include -I/usr/local/include/ruby-1.9.1/x86_64-linux -I/usr/local/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/backward -I/usr/local/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I.   -Wall -g -rdynamic -fPIC -O3 -ggdb -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-long-long   -o locker.o -c locker.cc
       g++ -I. -I/tmp/build_1feat0v36ur6g/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/libv8-3.11.8.3-x86_64-linux/vendor/v8/include -I/usr/local/include/ruby-1.9.1/x86_64-linux -I/usr/local/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/backward -I/usr/local/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I.   -Wall -g -rdynamic -fPIC -O3 -ggdb -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-long-long   -o constraints.o -c constraints.cc
       g++ -I. -I/tmp/build_1feat0v36ur6g/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/libv8-3.11.8.3-x86_64-linux/vendor/v8/include -I/usr/local/include/ruby-1.9.1/x86_64-linux -I/usr/local/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/backward -I/usr/local/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I.   -Wall -g -rdynamic -fPIC -O3 -ggdb -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-long-long   -o exception.o -c exception.cc
       g++ -I. -I/tmp/build_1feat0v36ur6g/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/libv8-3.11.8.3-x86_64-linux/vendor/v8/include -I/usr/local/include/ruby-1.9.1/x86_64-linux -I/usr/local/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/backward -I/usr/local/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I.   -Wall -g -rdynamic -fPIC -O3 -ggdb -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-long-long   -o context.o -c context.cc
       g++ -I. -I/tmp/build_1feat0v36ur6g/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/libv8-3.11.8.3-x86_64-linux/vendor/v8/include -I/usr/local/include/ruby-1.9.1/x86_64-linux -I/usr/local/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/backward -I/usr/local/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I.   -Wall -g -rdynamic -fPIC -O3 -ggdb -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-long-long   -o string.o -c string.cc
       g++ -I. -I/tmp/build_1feat0v36ur6g/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/libv8-3.11.8.3-x86_64-linux/vendor/v8/include -I/usr/local/include/ruby-1.9.1/x86_64-linux -I/usr/local/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/backward -I/usr/local/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I.   -Wall -g -rdynamic -fPIC -O3 -ggdb -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-long-long   -o value.o -c value.cc
       g++ -I. -I/tmp/build_1feat0v36ur6g/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/libv8-3.11.8.3-x86_64-linux/vendor/v8/include -I/usr/local/include/ruby-1.9.1/x86_64-linux -I/usr/local/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/backward -I/usr/local/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I.   -Wall -g -rdynamic -fPIC -O3 -ggdb -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-long-long   -o object.o -c object.cc
       g++ -I. -I/tmp/build_1feat0v36ur6g/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/libv8-3.11.8.3-x86_64-linux/vendor/v8/include -I/usr/local/include/ruby-1.9.1/x86_64-linux -I/usr/local/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/backward -I/usr/local/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I.   -Wall -g -rdynamic -fPIC -O3 -ggdb -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-long-long   -o message.o -c message.cc
       g++ -I. -I/tmp/build_1feat0v36ur6g/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/libv8-3.11.8.3-x86_64-linux/vendor/v8/include -I/usr/local/include/ruby-1.9.1/x86_64-linux -I/usr/local/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/backward -I/usr/local/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I.   -Wall -g -rdynamic -fPIC -O3 -ggdb -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-long-long   -o script.o -c script.cc
       g++ -I. -I/tmp/build_1feat0v36ur6g/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/libv8-3.11.8.3-x86_64-linux/vendor/v8/include -I/usr/local/include/ruby-1.9.1/x86_64-linux -I/usr/local/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/backward -I/usr/local/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I.   -Wall -g -rdynamic -fPIC -O3 -ggdb -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-long-long   -o signature.o -c signature.cc
       g++ -I. -I/tmp/build_1feat0v36ur6g/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/libv8-3.11.8.3-x86_64-linux/vendor/v8/include -I/usr/local/include/ruby-1.9.1/x86_64-linux -I/usr/local/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/backward -I/usr/local/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I.   -Wall -g -rdynamic -fPIC -O3 -ggdb -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-long-long   -o trycatch.o -c trycatch.cc
       g++ -I. -I/tmp/build_1feat0v36ur6g/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/libv8-3.11.8.3-x86_64-linux/vendor/v8/include -I/usr/local/include/ruby-1.9.1/x86_64-linux -I/usr/local/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/backward -I/usr/local/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I.   -Wall -g -rdynamic -fPIC -O3 -ggdb -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-long-long   -o stack.o -c stack.cc
       g++ -I. -I/tmp/build_1feat0v36ur6g/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/libv8-3.11.8.3-x86_64-linux/vendor/v8/include -I/usr/local/include/ruby-1.9.1/x86_64-linux -I/usr/local/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/backward -I/usr/local/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I.   -Wall -g -rdynamic -fPIC -O3 -ggdb -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-long-long   -o gc.o -c gc.cc
       g++ -I. -I/tmp/build_1feat0v36ur6g/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/libv8-3.11.8.3-x86_64-linux/vendor/v8/include -I/usr/local/include/ruby-1.9.1/x86_64-linux -I/usr/local/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/backward -I/usr/local/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I.   -Wall -g -rdynamic -fPIC -O3 -ggdb -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-long-long   -o backref.o -c backref.cc
       g++ -I. -I/tmp/build_1feat0v36ur6g/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/libv8-3.11.8.3-x86_64-linux/vendor/v8/include -I/usr/local/include/ruby-1.9.1/x86_64-linux -I/usr/local/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/backward -I/usr/local/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I.   -Wall -g -rdynamic -fPIC -O3 -ggdb -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-long-long   -o rr.o -c rr.cc
       g++ -I. -I/tmp/build_1feat0v36ur6g/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/libv8-3.11.8.3-x86_64-linux/vendor/v8/include -I/usr/local/include/ruby-1.9.1/x86_64-linux -I/usr/local/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/backward -I/usr/local/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I.   -Wall -g -rdynamic -fPIC -O3 -ggdb -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-long-long   -o date.o -c date.cc
       g++ -I. -I/tmp/build_1feat0v36ur6g/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/libv8-3.11.8.3-x86_64-linux/vendor/v8/include -I/usr/local/include/ruby-1.9.1/x86_64-linux -I/usr/local/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/backward -I/usr/local/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I.   -Wall -g -rdynamic -fPIC -O3 -ggdb -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-long-long   -o handles.o -c handles.cc
       g++ -I. -I/tmp/build_1feat0v36ur6g/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/libv8-3.11.8.3-x86_64-linux/vendor/v8/include -I/usr/local/include/ruby-1.9.1/x86_64-linux -I/usr/local/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/backward -I/usr/local/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I.   -Wall -g -rdynamic -fPIC -O3 -ggdb -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-long-long   -o v8.o -c v8.cc
       g++ -I. -I/tmp/build_1feat0v36ur6g/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/libv8-3.11.8.3-x86_64-linux/vendor/v8/include -I/usr/local/include/ruby-1.9.1/x86_64-linux -I/usr/local/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/backward -I/usr/local/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I.   -Wall -g -rdynamic -fPIC -O3 -ggdb -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-long-long   -o init.o -c init.cc
       g++ -I. -I/tmp/build_1feat0v36ur6g/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/libv8-3.11.8.3-x86_64-linux/vendor/v8/include -I/usr/local/include/ruby-1.9.1/x86_64-linux -I/usr/local/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/backward -I/usr/local/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I.   -Wall -g -rdynamic -fPIC -O3 -ggdb -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-long-long   -o heap.o -c heap.cc
       g++ -I. -I/tmp/build_1feat0v36ur6g/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/libv8-3.11.8.3-x86_64-linux/vendor/v8/include -I/usr/local/include/ruby-1.9.1/x86_64-linux -I/usr/local/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/backward -I/usr/local/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I.   -Wall -g -rdynamic -fPIC -O3 -ggdb -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-long-long   -o constants.o -c constants.cc
       g++ -I. -I/tmp/build_1feat0v36ur6g/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/libv8-3.11.8.3-x86_64-linux/vendor/v8/include -I/usr/local/include/ruby-1.9.1/x86_64-linux -I/usr/local/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/backward -I/usr/local/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I.   -Wall -g -rdynamic -fPIC -O3 -ggdb -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-long-long   -o external.o -c external.cc
       g++ -I. -I/tmp/build_1feat0v36ur6g/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/libv8-3.11.8.3-x86_64-linux/vendor/v8/include -I/usr/local/include/ruby-1.9.1/x86_64-linux -I/usr/local/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/backward -I/usr/local/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I.   -Wall -g -rdynamic -fPIC -O3 -ggdb -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-long-long   -o accessor.o -c accessor.cc
       g++ -I. -I/tmp/build_1feat0v36ur6g/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/libv8-3.11.8.3-x86_64-linux/vendor/v8/include -I/usr/local/include/ruby-1.9.1/x86_64-linux -I/usr/local/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/backward -I/usr/local/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I.   -Wall -g -rdynamic -fPIC -O3 -ggdb -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-long-long   -o function.o -c function.cc
       g++ -I. -I/tmp/build_1feat0v36ur6g/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/libv8-3.11.8.3-x86_64-linux/vendor/v8/include -I/usr/local/include/ruby-1.9.1/x86_64-linux -I/usr/local/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/backward -I/usr/local/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I.   -Wall -g -rdynamic -fPIC -O3 -ggdb -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-long-long   -o primitive.o -c primitive.cc
       g++ -I. -I/tmp/build_1feat0v36ur6g/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/libv8-3.11.8.3-x86_64-linux/vendor/v8/include -I/usr/local/include/ruby-1.9.1/x86_64-linux -I/usr/local/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/backward -I/usr/local/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I.   -Wall -g -rdynamic -fPIC -O3 -ggdb -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-long-long   -o invocation.o -c invocation.cc
       g++ -shared -o init.so template.o array.o locker.o constraints.o exception.o context.o string.o value.o object.o message.o script.o signature.o trycatch.o stack.o gc.o backref.o rr.o date.o handles.o v8.o init.o heap.o constants.o external.o accessor.o function.o primitive.o invocation.o -L. -L/usr/local/lib -Wl,-R/usr/local/lib /tmp/build_1feat0v36ur6g/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/libv8-3.11.8.3-x86_64-linux/vendor/v8/out/x64.release/obj.target/tools/gyp/libv8_base.a /tmp/build_1feat0v36ur6g/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/libv8-3.11.8.3-x86_64-linux/vendor/v8/out/x64.release/obj.target/tools/gyp/libv8_snapshot.a -L.  -rdynamic -Wl,-export-dynamic   -lpthread  -lpthread -lrt -ldl -lcrypt -lm   -lc
       /tmp/build_1feat0v36ur6g/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/libv8-3.11.8.3-x86_64-linux/vendor/v8/out/x64.release/obj.target/tools/gyp/libv8_base.a: could not read symbols: No such file or directory
       collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
       make: *** [init.so] Error 1
       Gem files will remain installed in /tmp/build_1feat0v36ur6g/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/therubyracer-0.11.0beta8 for inspection.
       Results logged to /tmp/build_1feat0v36ur6g/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/therubyracer-0.11.0beta8/ext/v8/gem_make.out
       An error occurred while installing therubyracer (0.11.0beta8), and Bundler cannot continue.
       Make sure that `gem install therubyracer -v '0.11.0beta8'` succeeds before bundling.
 !
 !     Failed to install gems via Bundler.
 !
 !     Heroku push rejected, failed to compile Ruby/rails app
```

Has anyone else encountered this?

I'm guessing that Heroku has an issue with therubyracer, but any ideas on how I can work around this?

Comment: Any reason why you can't just install bootstrap directly into your assets directory?

Answer (score 0):

[This commit](https://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails/commit/44cfe7f25a0fd305c763f1a299a418a92d027e64) was just made which removes therubyracer from the gemspec, I'm guessing that should solve your problem. Just run `bundle update twitter-bootstrap-rails` to get it and then push again to heroku.

Comment: Having upgraded I get a load error now from the server:

`Error starting application
Your Rack app raised an exception when Pow tried to run it.
LoadError: cannot load such file -- twitter/bootstrap/rails`